# HP Pavilion g6. Ubuntu 12.04. Kernel 3.5.0-39. Wifi/bluetooth suddenly stopped working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, kernel, hp-pavilion

So, wifi was working fine till yesterday. There's suddenly an issue - I can't even see the "enable wireless" option on the GUI top menu.

Here's info:

iwconfig gives me this:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig gives me this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:92:4a:4f:7a:e5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.241  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2a92:4aff:fe4f:7ae5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:50857091 (50.8 MB)  TX bytes:2485146 (2.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:69884 (69.8 KB)  TX bytes:69884 (69.8 KB)
```

lspci gives me this:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
```

ifconfig wlan0 up gives me this:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Comment: When did you last run updates in Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you originally install the driver for your Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290? In 12.04, it must be installed by hand. Do you need to re-compile?

Comment: @Colyn1337 - Ran update about 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @chili555 - I installed it manually, yes, if that's what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the recent updates was an updated kernel version, known as linux-image. When you installed the driver manually, you compiled it for your then-currently running kernel version only. Now you must build the driver for your newer kernel version. Please open a terminal and do:

```
cd Desktop/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
```

...or wherever you downloaded and extracted the file you used to compile the driver originally.

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt3290sta
```

Your wireless should now be working. Whenever a newer kernel version is installed, repeat the process.

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver! Is there a way to make a script which automatically does this everytime the kernel is upgraded?

Comment: There is probably a way to do it with dkms. I have no such experience. I urge you to Google or post a new question. Here is a start: http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/nach-update-kein-wlan-mehr-433/2/#post-5561332 About 3/4 of the way down the page is the dkms stuff. I haven't verified it.